# I have to create dynamic divs on button click using bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

As seen in the above pic i need to add the div as shown above when user clicks on the Add button. The difficulty here is i need to do it using bootstrap i.e. all the div's should rearrange based on the resolution i.e. for 1920x900, 1280x600, 980x1280, 800x1280, 768x1024, 360x640.
Do let me know how i can do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Google for "jquery add div"](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=jquery%20add%20div) is your friend. Regarding Bootstrap grid system, it is well explained on their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to learn about Bootstrap's grid system. Basically we say that the max width is 12, so if you want 4 containers with equal width you just divide 12 by 4 which is 3. Therefore `col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3` is the classes we wanna add to each div.

I have made a quick example of how this could work.

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('.container .row').append('<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">Div 1</div><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">Div 2</div><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">Div 3</div><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">Div 4</div>');
});
```

```css
.col-md-3{
    height: 100px;
    background-color:rgb(230,230,230);
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Click me!</button>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about setting up your grid's classes properly on the DIVs, and they should rearrange when the screen is resized. For example, if you want 4 DIVs per row on a medium screen, you would do this :

```
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

Then, if you only want 3 DIVs per row on small screens, you add another class ...

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"></div>
```

And finally, to get two DIVs on the smallest devices ... (<768px)

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
```

Everything is explained [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

As for adding the DIVs on button click, this is very easy, look on Google and you'll be able to find several examples.